# Inconsistency in registering and logging in labels

Tags: discussion, design

Why are the labels for registering and signing up using different terminology?

```
Sign up 
Log in
```

[image: sign up and log in]

Is there are problem with using the label `Sign in` ?

One argument can be it is to avoid confusion, but, personally I still end up reading both the labels since they are using different words.

Is there a study backing the use of different labels for registering and signing in to reduce user errors?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two questions ([one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29492/what-is-the-name-of-the-button-that-lead-to-a-login-and-register-page-one-page/29495#29495), [two](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20595/sign-up-vs-create-an-account/)) that you might find interesting.

One of the answers contained a link to [this article](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-sign-up-and-sign-in-should-never-go-together/) which states:

> The ideal combination is one that allows users to quickly distinguish one action from the other without thinking. The more similar your actions are, the harder it is to tell the difference between the two. You can make your sign up and sign in faster for users to process by using action phrases that are completely distinct from each other. For instance, combining “Sign In” with an action phrase like “Create Account” or “Join Now” is much clearer because there are no similarities between the two. They don’t use the same verbs like “Sign Up” and “Sign In”, and they both don’t end in similar prepositions like “Sign Up” and “Log In”.

[image]

Granted none of the answers or the article have "Research"...

Comment: I definitely agree with the article and the suggestion seems apt. I am still curious to see the difference between sign-up/log-in and sign-up/sign-in. Sign-up/log-in will be better but, by how much?